# How to add/remove text in between string(statement) using js?

Tags: javascript

How to add/remove text in between string(statement) using js?

For example:

```
var string =  "<html> </html>"
```

Now, the string should contain

```
<html> <body> </body> </html>
```

Comment: If jQuery is new to you, try considering it, it makes such simple & complex tasks quite easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you need. You can use regEx in javascript or the plain old string search and replace functions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the doco for the [various string methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_unrelated_to_HTML).

You can extract pieces of a string using [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

You can determine the starting position of a particular substring using [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

You can replace parts of the string that match a pattern using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

For your specific example it is not clear what criteria you have used to determine where to insert the string with the body tags, e.g., did you want to insert at the string's halfway point, or after the first closing ">", or after the first space, or find an html opening and closing tag pair with nothing but white-space content, or...?

The following would do it after the first closing ">":

```
var str = "<html> </html>";

var i = str.indexOf(">");
if (i !== -1)
   str = str.substr(0, i) + "<body> </body>" + str.substr(i + 1);
```

Note that in most situations you don't want to be using JavaScript to manipulate html markup as a string, much better to use DOM manipulation functions.

Comment: simply we can use replace method to get that.

eg
string.replace("`<html>`","`<html><body></body>`");